# django-Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am trying to create a static file to show my image in Django 3.8.3

I am using this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html>
    <head>
        <title>empty page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>welcome to empty zone</h1>
        <h1> my name is {{name}} </h1>
        <img src="{% 'images/Django_Unchained_logo.jpg' %}" alt="no image found">
    </body>
</html>
```

I already registered static in settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
TEMPLATE_DIR=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')
STATIC_DIR=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
```

#staticfiles

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR=[
    STATIC_DIR,
]
```

Comment: You missed the tag name.

Comment: Klaus D thanks I get it, now it's working

Answer (score 1):

you are missing `static` tag in `{% 'images/Django_Unchained_logo.jpg' %}`

it should be

```
<img src="{% static 'images/Django_Unchained_logo.jpg' %}" alt="no image found">
```